# What is Eclipse Ctrl+O shortcut equivalent in Android Studio?

Tags: android, eclipse, android-studio, find

I tried finding a method in a class using <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>O</kbd>. But that doesn't work.
I was wondering how do we find a method in a class.

Comment: @JaswinderWadali are so wrong! SO is just to it and much more!

Comment: @JaswinderWadali your english is crazy dude!

Comment: android studio sucks, such Q's make like easier, plese do not discourage it

Answer (score 14, accepted):

The equivalent shortcut in IntelliJ based IDEs is <kbd>CTRL</kbd> + <kbd>F12</kbd>.

You can also use <kbd>CTRL</kbd>+<kbd>ALT</kbd>+<kbd>SHIFT</kbd>+<kbd>N</kbd> or <kbd>SHIFT</kbd>+<kbd>SHIFT</kbd> to navigate to symbols (like methods).

Comment: Note: if you're looking to remap the shortcut, the command name is _File Structure_ and it's under the _Navigate_ menu